# Beautifulsoup - scrape search results

Tags: python, web, search, beautifulsoup

I am new to Beautifulsoup and I am trying to learn how to scrape search results from websites.

I've been able to practice on scraping websites, but I've reached a block with results from search forms.

For example, I would like to find all the names, addresses of libraries located in [NSW](http://www.nla.gov.au/apps/libraries)

How would I go about that? How can I retreive the results based on that search criteria, and open that results page with Beautifulsoup?

Thanks and sorry for my beginner question!

Xx

Comment: Look for the from data, `libstate`, `dosearch`, `termtype`, `action`. Pass those with your request and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

library_list = []

data = {'action' : 'LibSearch', 'termtype' : 'Keyword', 'libstate' : 'NSW', 'dosearch' : 'Search', 'libtype' : 'All', 'chunk' : 20}

page = requests.get("http://www.nla.gov.au/apps/libraries/", params=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


libraries = soup.find_all("a")


for library in libraries[5:]:
    print(library.text)
    library_list.append(library.text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Design Centre Enmore Library
Sydney Institute

A.B. 'Banjo' Paterson Library
Sydney Grammar School
.
.

ANSTO Library
Australian Nuclear Science and Technology Organisation

.
.
```

> Note: Change the `chunk` size in the `data` params to get as many
>   libraries as you want.